# A problem on Cumulative Distribution Functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a discrete random variable with pmf given by $\ p_X(x_i) = p_i $ for i = 1,,,,, n,
and Y = aX + b, where a > 0, b are constants. Show that, for any y,
$ F_y(y) = F_X \frac{(y-b)}{a} $

Comment: What about your own thoughts?

Comment: I know that $ F_y(y)=P(Y<=y) $ and similarly for $F_x(x)$. It seems straight forward by substitution but i am not able to get the final result neatly. Can you help me there

Comment: There's no such thing as a "cumulative density function".  The word "cumulative" and the word "density" contradict each other.  I changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\Pr(X\le x)=F_X(x)$$
we have $$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(aX+b\le y)=\Pr(X\le\frac{y-b}{a})=F_X(\frac{y-b}{a})$$

Comment: Awesome!! I think this was what i thought but many thanks for posting this

Comment: Your'e welcome. The last equation just uses the definition of cdf in the top.